# New Headless Chrome in Geb

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, groovy, geb, headless-browser

I'm trying to get my project that uses Geb to run the beta channel of Chrome in headless mode.

I can reproduce the issue using the [Geb Gradle example project](https://github.com/geb/geb-example-gradle).

In GebConfig.groovy, I've got this block to define chrome:

```
environments {

    // run via “./gradlew chromeTest”
    // See: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver
    chrome {
        driver = {
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome()

            String chromiumPath = "/usr/bin/chromium-browser"
            String macChromePath = "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"
            String macCanaryChrome = "/Applications/Google Chrome Canary.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome Canary"

            def chromiumBinary = new File(chromiumPath)
            def isAgent = chromiumBinary.exists()
            def macChromeBinary = new File(macChromePath)
            if (isAgent) {
                options.setBinary(chromiumBinary) //Set binary using file to avoid NoClassDefFound error on mac
            } else if (macChromeBinary.exists()) {
                options.setBinary(macChromeBinary)
            }

            options.addArguments("headless", "disable-gpu", "remote-debugging-port=9515")
            capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options)
            new ChromeDriver(capabilities)
        }
    }
}
```

While this does start a headless version of Chrome running, communication fails when I run the tests with `./gradlew chromeTest`. The error printed to the terminal window is as follows:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.24.417412 (ac882d3ce7c0d99292439bf3405780058fcca0a6) on port 11187
Only local connections are allowed.
Starting ChromeDriver 2.24.417412 (ac882d3ce7c0d99292439bf3405780058fcca0a6) on port 8685
Only local connections are allowed.
Starting ChromeDriver 2.24.417412 (ac882d3ce7c0d99292439bf3405780058fcca0a6) on port 38557
Only local connections are allowed.

failed to create driver from callback 'script1495748981469190891056$_run_closure2$_closure3$_closure4@a8e7a58'
geb.driver.DriverCreationException: failed to create driver from callback 'script1495748981469190891056$_run_closure2$_closure3$_closure4@a8e7a58'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:255)
    at geb.driver.CallbackDriverFactory.getDriver(CallbackDriverFactory.groovy:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MethodMetaProperty$GetBeanMethodMetaProperty.getProperty(MethodMetaProperty.java:76)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePogoPropertySite.callGetProperty(GetEffectivePogoPropertySite.java:48)
    at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory$_getDriver_closure3.doCall(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:85)
    at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory$_getDriver_closure3.doCall(CachingDriverFactory.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory$SimpleCache.get(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MethodMetaProperty$GetBeanMethodMetaProperty.getProperty(MethodMetaProperty.java:76)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePogoPropertySite.callGetProperty(GetEffectivePogoPropertySite.java:48)
    at geb.Configuration.createDriver(Configuration.groovy:382)
    at geb.Configuration.getDriver(Configuration.groovy:371)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MethodMetaProperty$GetBeanMethodMetaProperty.getProperty(MethodMetaProperty.java:76)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePogoPropertySite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(GetEffectivePogoPropertySite.java:68)
    at geb.Browser.getDriver(Browser.groovy:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MethodMetaProperty$GetBeanMethodMetaProperty.getProperty(MethodMetaProperty.java:76)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePogoPropertySite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(GetEffectivePogoPropertySite.java:68)
    at geb.navigator.factory.BrowserBackedNavigatorFactory.<init>(BrowserBackedNavigatorFactory.groovy:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:255)
    at geb.Configuration.createNavigatorFactory(Configuration.groovy:417)
    at geb.Configuration$createNavigatorFactory.call(Unknown Source)
    at geb.Browser.createNavigatorFactory(Browser.groovy:133)
    at geb.Browser.getNavigatorFactory(Browser.groovy:121)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MethodMetaProperty$GetBeanMethodMetaProperty.getProperty(MethodMetaProperty.java:76)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePogoPropertySite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(GetEffectivePogoPropertySite.java:68)
    at geb.Page.init(Page.groovy:144)
    at geb.Page$init.call(Unknown Source)
    at geb.Browser.createPage(Browser.groovy:855)
    at geb.Browser.to(Browser.groovy:548)
    at geb.Browser$to.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at geb.Browser.to(Browser.groovy:537)
    at geb.Browser.to(Browser.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1218)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:925)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:908)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:168)
    at geb.junit4.GebTest.methodMissing(GebTest.groovy:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:944)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1267)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1220)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
    at GebishOrgTest.canGetToTheCurrentBookOfGeb(GebishOrgTest.groovy:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatchman$1.evaluate(TestWatchman.java:53)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:377)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417412 (ac882d3ce7c0d99292439bf3405780058fcca0a6),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.4 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.02 seconds
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'ACA8006C.ipt.aol.com', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:8d3:2303:79b7:d548%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.4', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$22(ProtocolHandshake.java:365)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:368)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:159)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:250)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:236)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:184)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247)
    at script1495748981469190891056$_run_closure2$_closure3$_closure4.doCall(script1495748981469190891056.groovy:46)
    at script1495748981469190891056$_run_closure2$_closure3$_closure4.doCall(script1495748981469190891056.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:925)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:908)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:168)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeClosure(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:574)
    at geb.driver.CallbackDriverFactory.getDriver(CallbackDriverFactory.groovy:29)
    ... 157 more
```

Note that multiple ChromeDrivers are getting started on various ports. I'd hazard that the primary issue is that the ChromeDriver server isn't able to talk to the headless Chrome.

Based on a couple of Python examples I've read (which are using Selenium), I'm pretty sure this configuration is correct.

- https://intoli.com/blog/running-selenium-with-headless-chrome/
- https://duo.com/blog/driving-headless-chrome-with-python

The crux of the problem seems to be that headless Chrome launches (I can go to http://localhost:9515 in my browser and see it running with just the empty `data;` page), but the chromedriver can't communicate with it.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, so I managed to get this working in Geb's sample Gradle project with the following GebConfig.groovy, BUT, I had to update the version of ChromeDriver in the build.gradle file from 2.24 to 2.29 for it to play nicely with the newest version of Chrome.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities

waiting {
        timeout = 2
    }

    environments {

        // run via “./gradlew chromeTest”
        // See: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver
        chrome {
            driver = {
                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()
                DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome()

                String chromiumPath = "/usr/bin/chromium-browser"
                String macChromePath = "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"

                def chromiumBinary = new File(chromiumPath)
                def isAgent = chromiumBinary.exists()
                def macChromeBinary = new File(macChromePath)
                if (isAgent) {
                    options.setBinary(chromiumBinary) //Set binary using file to avoid NoClassDefFound error on mac
                } else if (macChromeBinary.exists()) {
                    options.setBinary(macChromeBinary)
                }

                options.addArguments("headless")
                capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options)
                new ChromeDriver(capabilities)
            }
        }
    }
```

It seems like adding the `remote-debugging-port` option is what causes the slowdown/breakage. `disable-gpu` seems fine, though.

```
options.addArguments("headless", "disable-gpu")
```

Comment: Notably, the maintainer was kind enough to merge my PR. https://github.com/geb/geb-example-gradle/pull/27